# Navigation Drawer Template in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, navigation-drawer

I was fully confused in this navigation drawer.i am studying lot's of tutorials but i am not understand.i want how do use the **android studio (Template) navigation drawer** or how to use  list view using navigation drawer,if we are using list view then how to add the image in the first row then how to add the dashboard fragment in navigation drawer.please give any reference or any example program.Thanks for advance.

Comment: Go through [link](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html)  or [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you created an activity as Navigation Drawer Activity in Android Studio, Android Studio will be created a set of layout.

- activity_layout.xml (or the name of Activity)
- app_bar.xml (for toolbar)
- content.xml (for content)
- nav_header.xml (for header view of navigation drawer)

The first item of the navigation drawer (the first row of the list that you say) is nav_header.xml. In this layout you can set the first row.
Also on the menu folder is created a .xml, with activity_drawer.xml as name, with the items of navigation.

Something like this:

***activity_drawe.xml***

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
   <item
    android:id="@+id/search"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    android:title="@string/drawer_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="always" />

   <group android:title="@string/drawer_eltiempo"
       android:enabled="true"
       android:checkableBehavior="single">
    <item android:id="@+id/eltiempo"
          android:enabled="false"
          android:title="@string/drawer_eltiempo">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/tutiempo"
                android:title="@string/drawer_tutiempo"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/paises"
                android:title="@string/drawer_tiempoPaises"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/cercaTi"
                android:title="@string/drawer_cercaTi"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/web"
                android:title="@string/drawer_nuestraWeb"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/config"
                android:title="@string/drawer_configuracion"/>
        </menu>
    </item>
  </group>
</menu>
```

***nav_header.xml***

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
          android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
          android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
          android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:gravity="bottom">
</LinearLayout>
```

The names may change depending on the name of the activity.

If you want an example, just leave a few days and you'll have.